# Stack overflow during evaluation (looping recursion?)

Tags: ocaml

i'm new to ocaml and i'm trying to create a function that takes an int list and turn it into a list of int list that are have the first element + the second element, followed by the rest of the list, until there is one element left, for example:

```
[1; 2; 0; 4; 2; 1] 
[3; 0; 4; 2; 1]
[3; 4; 2; 1]
[7; 2; 1]
[9; 1]
[10]
```

And here is my code:

```
let rec nth l k =
  match l with
  | [] -> 0
  | s::t -> if k = 0 then s else nth t (k - 1);;

let no_first l =
  match l with
  | [] -> []
  | s::t -> t

let rec left_comp_once l =
  match l with
  | [] -> []
  | s::t -> (s + nth t 0) :: no_first t

let rec left_comps l =
  match l with 
  | [] -> []
  | s::t -> let x = (s + nth t 0) :: no_first t in
      [x] @ left_comps x
```

The left_comp_once function works, however, i get looping recursion error when i try the left_comps function

I cannot figure out where the issue is coming from

Also, i would like to have a return element in this format:

```
int list -> (int list) list
```

However, what i wrote gives me:

```
int list -> int list list
```

What do these parenthesis imply ?

Comment: The parenthesis only set the precedence. But in this case the precedence already is `(int list) list` even without the parenthesis. Parenthesis are only shown when required to override the existing order, like when taken a function as argument: `(int -> int) -> unit`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a cleaner way to do it, using pattern matching to get the first two elements of the list in a tail-recursive helper function:

```ml
let left_comps l =
  let rec helper l acc =
    match l with
        (* Empty list; return the accumulator *)
      | [] -> acc 
        (* Single element list; cons it to the accumulator *)
      | _ :: [] -> l :: acc 
        (* Two or more elements; add the first two together,
           cons the original to the accumulator and repeat with
           a new shorter list *)
      | a :: b :: t -> helper (a + b :: t) (l :: acc) in
  helper l []
```

With this definition,

```ml
left_comps [1; 2; 0; 4; 2; 1]
```

returns

```ml
[[10]; [9; 1]; [7; 2; 1]; [3; 4; 2; 1]; [3; 0; 4; 2; 1]; [1; 2; 0; 4; 2; 1]]
```

---

> What do these parenthesis imply?

Parenthesis in an ocaml type signature usually indicate a function. For example, `(int -> int)` means a function that takes an `int` argument and returns an `int`. You're just returning a list of lists of integers, hence `int list list`.

Answer (score 3):

If you look at this expression:

```
let x = (s + nth t 0) :: no_first t in
      [x] @ left_comps x
```

you can see that `x` can't possibly be an empty list. It always has at least one element. Therefore `left_comps` will never terminate when given a non-empty list.

Possibly you want to terminate the recursion when the incoming list has length < 2.